# Previous question edited into a completely different question, a bounty has also been put on the "new" question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, bounties

I've seen a question on which a bounty has just been set ([the question is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780049/swapping-of-images-becomes-ineffective-on-changing-orientation)). After a quick look (following the two comments) I saw that the question appeared after the owner simply edited the old question into something new and totally unrelated. How should this be handled (if it's not an accepted situation)? Can I simply answer the question or should I flag it?

Comment: I've rolled back their edit.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Of course the question can be rolled back, but the bounty was obviously targeted at the question from the edit. Now the user is left with a question for which he knows the answer and a useless bounty. Is there something to be done in this area?

Comment: Learn from their mistake.

Comment: *sigh*. Rollback war. I'd bet the person in question is question banned too.

Comment: *"This question has not received enough attention"*. It has now, but probably not the kind they were hoping for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is the same as if the question didn't have the bounty.

Assume that the question has no answers, is it acceptable?

I would say it depends on the votes:

- If the question is upvoted, then changing the subject matter completely is deceiving those voted the question up in the first place.
- If the question is downvoted, you're starting in a hole already, better to delete the original and just create a new question.

Either way, a new question should be asked, even if you have zero answers (and I would even say zero votes).

I say you flag it for moderator attention (it has been, and been dealt with).

Note in this case the bounty wasn't removed because the content completely changed, but because the question is close-worthy, and the question can't be closed without removing the bounty.